# VM Instance Service Account can't be recognized

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-iam

Although I've gave Owner role to that specific service, I can't use the permissions from my instances that I connect with SSH from my local.

Also can't upload my files to Storage bucket which I've created in cloud platform.

Here is the screenshots of the problem:

[image: Error in console]

[image: Cloud IAM Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the access token not having the appropriate permission scopes to conduct the required activity. To make sure you're using the auth scope of this service account appropriately, I recommend doing the following:

1. Run the command in the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create) inside the VM to
   create a new key for the service account. This will create a .json
   file inside the current directory containing the private
   authentication key for the service account.
2. Run the command in the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) to activate the
   service account.
3. Run the command: `$gcloud auth list` to check if this worked.
   In the output you should see an asterisk before the service
   account’s name, indicating that this is the service account you are
   currently using.
4. Now refer to the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable) and run the `$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Compute VMs have a setting for **Access Scopes**. This feature can limit the permissions that a service account has when attached to a virtual machine.

Go to the Google Cloud Console GUI, select your VM, stop the VM and then edit Acess Scopes to grant the permissions you require.

[Access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam)